# How to retrieve a web-api controller method(without database), from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, devextreme

**I want to retrieve the function/method written in controller of Web-Api, from javascript of multi-channel devextreme template.(need to show data from Web-API Controller in front-end, where data is not from server).**

Please suggest me which site I should refer/by writing simple code...

**Controller**

```
namespace WebApiODataService3.Controllers
{
    public class ShaileshsController : ODataController
    {
       public string GetShailesh()
        {
            return "say hello";
        }

    }
}
```

**shailesh.js of shailesh.dxview-from devextreme multichannel template**

```
Application2.shailesh = function (params) {
    "use strict";

    var viewModel = {
//  Put the binding properties here

};

    return viewModel;
};
```

Comment: 2 questions - 1. When you say retrieve, does it mean you want to invoke an action (function) written in a web api controller? 2. What do you mean by "where data is not from server"? Could you atleast write a skeleton code of what you are trying?

Comment: Answers-1.Yes;2.Normally we show the data from server ie.giving web-API url while creating front-end view(built in support of devextreme)

Comment: are you asking how to make an ajax call to the API?

Comment: Don't really get your question. But you could try making an ajax call as pointed by @ADyson

Comment: yes..@AnkitMittal

Comment: If you want to make an ajax call, there are lots of examples in existence. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+call+web+API+using+ajax&oq=how+to+call+web+API+using+ajax&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.5546j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 or https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&q=how+to+call+web+API+from+devextreme&oq=how+to+call+web+API+from+devextreme&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i21k1.32031.36293.0.36468.19.17.0.0.0.0.281.2191.0j2j8.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..10.8.1763...0j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1.jvv31LzrcGA - these 2nd set of results are specific to DevExtreme

Answer (score 1):

I think you ask for an example:

Classes

```
public class CustomModel
{
    public int var1 { get; set; }
    public string var2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubSetModel> subset { get; set; }
}

public class SubSetModel
{
    public string subvar1 { get; set; }
    public string subvar2 { get; set; }
}
```

Test Controller Methods

```
[Route("api/route/postaction")]
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<string> postaction(CustomModel data)
    {
        return Json<string>("ok");
    }
[Route("api/route/getaction")]
public dynamic getaction()
    {
        var data = new CustomModel() { var1 = 1, var2 = "ter" };
         data.subset = new List<SubSetModel>() { new SubSetModel() { subvar1 = "hi", subvar2 = "hola" } };
        return data;
    }
```

Call to getaction

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:45007/api/maestro/getaction",
        method: "GET",
        data: {}
    }).done(function (dataSel) {
        alert("OK");
    }).fail(function (dataSel) {
        alert("Fail");            
    });
```